# Indirect telnet connection with Java

Tags: java, ssh, telnet, jsch

### Scenario

I'm in a Java project where we have to communicate with the CLIs of other machines. Unfortunately, we can't connect to these other machines directly and another bad luck is that they only support telnet. So we have the following setup, which is carved in stone (of course):

```
application <---- telnet or ssh ----> gateway <---- telnet ----> machine_001
(10.0.0.1)                         (192.168.1.1)               (192.168.2.1)
                                                               (192.168.2.2)
                                                               (    ...    )
```

It's possible to connect via SSH or telnet to the gateway manually (e.g. using PuTTY), telnet from this shell to one of the machines and work with its CLI. As we want the communication to happen automatically, the application must be able to talk to the machines by itself; so I need a programmatic solution.

### What I've tried so far

After some research on the internet I've found a library called [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which looked promising, but I've encountered an evil problem. When the applications connects to the gateway, the telnet command and therefore the whole CLI of the target machine is one single command from application's viewpoint. So I'd have to struggle with a non-terminating InputStream, unsynchronized OutputStream and Threads if necessary.

The next try was to establish a SSH tunnel from L127.0.0.1:1234 to 192.168.2.1:23 (via the gateway), but with this configuration it's not possible to telnet to 127.0.0.1:1234 (neither programmatically nor manually).

### The actual question

How can I get my application to talk to the machines via the gateway using telnet?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I did see some JSch console playing demos. So don't give up on JSch yet.

Comment: You could implement telnet yourself using raw sockets. When you do, you will realize that telnet can hardly be called a protocol - it's not more than sending and receiving the raw terminal input and output. SSH, on the other hand, can get a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Philipp Telnet is considerably more complicated that that if the server starts sending Telnet commands (IAC ...).

Comment: @MarkusR I had a similar problem [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694499/java-perform-a-ftp-command-through-a-ssh-tunnel-with-jsch). Can't you develop an application that runs on the `gateway` machine? If you can, just send requests to this program and it will telnet `machine_001`.

Comment: @JoopEggen: We've switched already from JSch to apache.commons.net but I'll keep JSch in mind for future projects @Philipp: That's exactly what our legacy implementation does (in ~50k lines of code o.O) and we wanted to use a simple-to-use library instead @Maxbester: Unfortunately there's no way make any changes outside our application. @All: Thank you for your input, I've managed to implement something nice with apache.commons.net (handling the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` manually)